# Parsing user input from whitespaces in C

Tags: c, unix, c99

I am trying to parse user input from scanf() by using the white spaces. I wanted to separate each string as I will be using them as commands in UNIX.

Example
input: ls -l

Expected output:

```
This is a command ls
This is a parameter -l
```

This is where I have gotten so far.

```
int main() {
    char input[100];
    do{
        scanf("%s", input);
        char *token = strtok(input, " ");
        while (token != NULL){
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        printf("This is the command %s ", input);
        //printf("This is a parameter %s ", input[1]);This isn't C programming language but I'm unsure of how to do this.
        //system(input); does not work, here for context.


    }while(1);

}
```

Current output:
This is the command hello This is the command there

How can I separate the strings by spaces from the input by the user and use

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for that. `%s` only reads one word. You can do it but it's not worth the pain and effort. Use `fgets` to read the whole line then `strtok` to seperate into tokens.

Answer (score 0):

> `while (token != NULL){ token = strtok(NULL, " "); }`

Just add using inside this loop before strtok call. Here is an example https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

If you going to use this code I recommend to read about getopt function https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html

Comment: It is not clear what solution you propose. Maybe you should show a larger piece of code. Explain in your answer why `getopt` is related to the problem.